# Deferring evaluation of function-call arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-passing

I wrote a small logging class that takes two or more arguments:

```
void my_log(int level, pattern [, fillins...]);
```

(The pattern and fill-ins are processed in a sprintf-like manner.)

The implementation of `my_log` begins:

```
if ( level < _min_level ) return;
```

I thought this would tidily short-circuit the call to `very_elaborate_representation()` ...

```
my_log(DEBUG, "%s", my_object.very_elaborate_representation());
```

when **_min_level** is greater than **DEBUG**.

But it doesn't: apparently (and not surprisingly) arguments are evaluated before the function call.

The formatting is expensive, and intended only for debugging and trouble-shooting.

Is there a clean way to solve this problem with C++11, other than wrapping the call with an if-test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but this is how I have previously implemented a logging module:

**In the header file:**

```
#define LOG(level,...) do {if (level >= MIN_LEVEL) log_printf(__VA_ARGS__);} while (0)

void log_printf(const char* data,...);
```

**In the source file:**

```
void log_printf(const char* data,...)
{
    char str[64] = {0}; // You can think of other ways for allocating it
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,data);
    vsnprintf(str,sizeof(str),data,args);
    va_end(args);
    printf(str);
}
```

In order to issue a log message, you only need to call `LOG(SOME_LEVEL,some-parameters)`.

Comment: I didn't know that macros could use variadic arguments... this will work.  I'll leave the question open a little longer to see if there are any non-preprocessor solutions.